# What are Nullable Types in C#?

Tags: c#

```
   int? _fileControlNo = null;
   public int? FileControlNo
    {
        get { return _fileControlNo; }
        set { _fileControlNo = value; }
    }
```

I'm getting a syntax error when I assign null values to the above properties.

```
objDPRUtils.FileControlNo =sArrElements.Value(3)==null ? null : Convert.ToInt32(sArrElements.Value(3));
```

Please, can anyone explain to me why the error occurs if I'm able to set null value in valuetype object using Nullable Type.

Comment: Whats the exact error message ?

Comment: What is the error, and what is sArrElements?

Comment: The error message, I'm guessing was `Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'int' `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The results of the conditional operators need to be of the same type or types that can be implicitly convertible to each other.

In your case you have a `null` and an `Int32` - these violate that requirement.

If instead of an `Int32` you return a nullable `Int32`, the `null` can be implicitly converted to this type and your code will work (or alternatively, cast the `null` to an `int?`).

Answer (score 2):

Cast your `null` to `int?`

```
objDPRUtils.FileControlNo =sArrElements.Value(3)==null ? (int?) null : Convert.ToInt32(sArrElements.Value(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditional operator needs to return result of the same type and in your case its not possible for `null`

this should work

```
sArrElements.Value(3)==null ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(sArrElements.Value(3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign directly like this :

```
objDPRUtils.FileControlNo =sArrElements.Value(3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nullable types are exactly what they say they are:  simple value types that can also store a null value.
I would suggest that you do not need the last line of code at all.  you should be able to get away with:

```
objDPRUtils.FileControlNo =sArrElements.Value(3);
```

If you really want to assign another value in case of null, use the null coalescing operator ??

```
objDPRUtils.FileControlNo =sArrElements.Value(3)??0;
```

which in this case, would assign the value 0 to the `FileControlNo` in case of the right hand side being null.

Answer (score 0):

Your code mixes types null and Int32 cannnot be mixed in this instance like that. They need to be of the same type.

If you use `int.TryParse` and only attempt to set the value on success you will achieve the same result and can use `HasValue` on the field to determine if its null or not which is how nullable types are used typically

Silly example

```
class Program
{
    private static int? _fileControlNo;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] sArrElements = new string[] { "1", "2", "3", null };

        int result;
        if (int.TryParse(sArrElements[3], out result))
        {
            FileControlNo = result;
        }


        if (_fileControlNo.HasValue)
        {
            // do something here
        }
    }

    public static int? FileControlNo
    {
        get { return _fileControlNo; }
        set { _fileControlNo = value; }
    } 

}
```

you will note that your code inside the test for `HasValue` in this case will never execute because _fileControlNo cannot be set because tryParse always fails (change the indexer and that will change).